# Vagrant and symfony2

Tags: php, macos, apache, symfony, vagrant

I'm having kind of a bizzare issue related to installing Symfony2 from within a vagrant environment. The environment is set up correctly and is running a web server that is serving files from a folder that is shared with the vagrant environment that is located in the base directory of vagrant.

Basically, vagrant is initiated in directory foo and then within foo, there is a directory called webroot. Vagrant automagically shares the foo directory. An apache server is set up to run so that webroot is the base http directory. This all works fine and I am able to serve basic HTML, PHP and the MySQL connection is tested to be fine.

I used composer to install vagrant the recommended way, into directory inside /webroot/ called Symfony. All of the files now exist within the correct directory. The configuration is correct  and there are no items that Symfony claims need to be changed in /config.php.

The issue comes when I attempt to load /app_dev.php. It throws an exception claiming that it cannot create a file named cache in the /app directory.

As chmod +a is not supported within the vagrant box I am using, I elected to set permissions by uncommenting umask(0000) in app_dev. Assuming it was a permission problem, I tried using chmod to adjust the permissions both within the vagrant environment and within osx to 777 for everything.

What's strange is that when I chmod a file or directory inside the vagrant environment, it claims to set 777 correctly but then when I ls -l, the permissions have not changed. However, when I chmod a file or directory from OUTSIDE The vagrant environment within the webroot folder, the permissions persist. As symfony does not have r/w permissions within the environment, it cannot create the necessary cache and log files. When i run symfony from the command from osx, everything works fine.

Does anyone have any insight as to how to change the permissions for the /webroot directory so things within the vagrant environment can actually read and write to it as chmod doesn't appear to work?

Answer (score 15):

> Update as of 15th Jan 2016. Instructions for Vagrant 1.7.4+ and Symfony 3. **This works.**

On a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install, ACL was installed but I couldn't use +a or setfacl to fix the permissions issues, and of course, as soon as you change any permissions in terminal in vagrant, they're reset to vagrant:vagrant again.

I added the following to my vagrant file:

```
# Symfony needs to be able to write to it's cache, logs and sessions directory in var/
config.vm.synced_folder "./var", "/vagrant/var",
 :owner => 'vagrant',
 :group => 'www-data',
 :mount_options => ["dmode=775","fmode=666"]
```

This tells Vagrant to sync var/logs and var/cache (not to be confused with /var/, these are in the root Symfony directory) and have them owned by vagrant:www-data. This is the same as doing a `sudo chown vagrant:www-data var/`, except Vagrant now does it for you and enforces that instead of enforcing vagrant:vagrant.

**Note there are no 777 'hacks' here**.

As soon as I added that, I didn't get any more permissions errors in the apache log and I got a nice Symfony welcome screen. I hope that helps someone!

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day.

Comment: @MuzafarAli Look at the last vagrant docs and search for synced folder? Maybe they changed how you do it in 1.9.3? If you find anything I'm happy to accept additions to the answer or change it for "1.9.3: do this instead". From a cursory search I can't find any BC breaking API changes :-/

Comment: @Jimbo - Just checked it's working fine now.. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a question of user rights. Your apache + php is probably launched by root. You have to set rights with root.

Two possibilities :

```
sudo su
chmod -R 777 app/cache
```

or

```
sudo chown -v app/cache
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
```

You will probably have to do the same thing with the log file.

My vagrant file if you need it :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"  #Box Name
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box" #Box Location
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
      virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/synced/", :nfs => true
  #config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080 # Forward 8080 rquest to vagrant 80 port
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "1.2.3.4"
  config.vm.network :public_network
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant.sh"
end
```

vagrant.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#VM Global Config
apt-get update

#Linux requirement
apt-get install -y vim git

#Apache Install
apt-get install -y apache2

#Apache Configuration
rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /home/vagrant/synced/web /var/www
chmod -R 755 /home/vagrant/synced

#Php Install
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5
apt-get update

apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5

#Php Divers
apt-get install -y php5-intl php-apc php5-gd php5-curl

#PhpUnit
apt-get install -y phpunit
pear upgrade pear
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit


#Php Configuration
sed -i "s/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 10M/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/short_open_tag = On/short_open_tag = Off/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/;date.timezone =/date.timezone = Europe\/London/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 1024M/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/_errors = Off/_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

#Reload apache configuration
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload

#Composer
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
mv -f composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer.phar'

#Postgres
apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-client php5-pgsql
su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c \"alter user postgres with password 'vagrant';\""
```

Comment: This dosen't work. Chmod-ing or Chowning within the vagrant enviroment, even as a super user immediately reverts and the permissions/ownership aren't changed even though the commands execute successfully. Any insight into how to get the Chmod or Chown commands to persist.

Comment: Figured it out! The issue was that the fmode and dmode were set incorrectly as the vagrant folder was mounted over vboxsf. I simply added the line  `config.vm.synced_folder "../gipsydanger/", "/vagrant", :extra => 'dmode=777,fmode=777'` to my Vagrantfile. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have taken some of this answer with slight enhancements and made it into a ready-to-use provisioning module, especially for the use with Symfony2. Posted it on [Github](https://github.com/Lukx/vagrant-lamp)

Comment: @IsaacDiamondn Thanks for the comment! Also worked for me. Just a note: the `:extra` param was renamed to `:mount_options`, so the line should be `config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]`

Comment: The suggestion by @pau.moreno worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Today I learned that it's important to read comments. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3):

An updated answer for nfs:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", type:nfs, :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me other than changing location of cache and logs folder to /tmp

**AppKernel.php**

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['test','dev'])) {
        return '/tmp/sfcache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }
    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['test','dev'])) {
        return '/tmp/sflogs/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }
    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```